Volume control on EQ & Amp circuit
I am trying to modify the circuit below by adding a volume control. I am thinking I would replace resistors R106/R206 with a logarithmic pot. I am also not sure why there are a pair of resistors (R106 & R106SOTO).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The original circuit is described here on an Instructable page


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Might be easier putting the pot before C101/201.
